# Add dots to a TextView like in a receipt

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, android-view

I want to implement something like a product list in a receipt: 
Bread ......................................... 20
Milk ............................................ 10
Cookies with jam ...................... 15
Smartphone 10GB 3GHz
1GB RAM NFC 10MPx 
camera .................................... 400

Item name (Bread, Milk) I think it shoud be a `TextView`, which I need to fill with dots.
Money (20, 10) is another `TextView` which shoud be aligned to the right of a screen.

Any ideas how to do this? Maybe I need to inherit the `TextView` class and override onDraw()?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: try `textview.append()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have the solution. Maybe it will help someone.**

1. File check_info_item.xml:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal">
   <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/txt_fake_value"
             android:textSize="18dp"
             android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
   <example.com.CheckInfoTextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/txt_fake_info"
             android:textSize="18dp"
             android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt_fake_value"/>
   <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/txt_check_info_value"
             android:text=""
             android:textSize="18dp"
             android:textColor="#000"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@id/txt_fake_info"/>
   <example.com.CheckInfoTextView
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:textSize="18dp"
           android:textColor="#000"
           android:id="@+id/txt_check_info"
           android:text=""
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt_check_info_value"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Code to fill the info fields (in the Activity):

   ```
       View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.check_info_item, null);
       //Fake fields needed to align base fields in the xml file
       TextView txtFakeValue = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_fake_value);
       txtFakeValue.setText(String.valueOf(pair.second));

       TextView txtFake = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_fake_info);
       txtFake.setText(pair.first);

       TextView txtValue = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_check_info_value);
       txtValue.setText(String.valueOf(pair.second));

       TextView txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_check_info);
       txtTitle.setText(pair.first);
   ```
3. And the CheckInfoTextView:

   ```
   public class CheckInfoTextView extends TextView {


       public CheckInfoTextView(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public CheckInfoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       public CheckInfoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       }

       @Override
       public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
           super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
           if(!hasWindowFocus) return;

           int requiredDots = getRequiredDotsNumber();
           if(requiredDots == 0) {
               String text = getText().toString();
               StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
               result.append(text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(' ')));
               result.append("\n");
               result.append(text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
               setText(result.toString());

               requiredDots = getRequiredDotsNumber();
           }
           String dots = "";
           for (int i = 0; i < requiredDots; ++i) {
               dots += " .";
           }
           setText(getText() + dots);
       }

       private int getRequiredDotsNumber() {
           final int width = getWidth();
           final int lastLineWidth = (int) getLayout().getLineWidth(getLineCount() - 1);
           final int availableWidthForDots = width - lastLineWidth;
           final int widthOfOneDot = getWidthOfOneDot();
           final int widthOfTwoDotsWithSpace = getWidthOfTwoDotsWithSpace();
           final int widthOfSpace = widthOfTwoDotsWithSpace - (widthOfOneDot * 2);
           final int widthOfDotWithSpace = widthOfSpace + widthOfOneDot;
           int numberOfDots = availableWidthForDots / widthOfDotWithSpace;
           return numberOfDots;
       }

       private int getWidthOfTwoDotsWithSpace() {
          return getStringWidth(". .");
       }

       private int getWidthOfOneDot() {
          return getStringWidth(".");
       }

       private int getStringWidth(String text) {
           Rect dotBounds = new Rect();
           getPaint().getTextBounds(text,0,text.length(),dotBounds);
           return dotBounds.width();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You should create THREE TextViews for each row, layed out one next to another:

1. TextView With product name (e.g. 'beer')
2. TextView with dots
3. TextView with number (e.g. '20')

Then put one product in one row. The Row should be relative layout where:

- TextView no. 1 is aligned to left edge, with width set to wrap content
- TextView no. 3 is aligneg to right edge, with width set to wrap content
- TextView no. 2 is toLeftOf TV no. 3 and toRightOf TV no.1 and it should be filled with big amount of dots in XML file. this will never be changed.

This will work, since the TV no.2 will have width that will shrink and will always be fitted between product name and the price. believe me :)

Comment: But what if TextView no. 1 has more than one line (e.g. Smartphone product in the question). The textView will be stretched to the width of the most wide row (in the example it is the first row - "Smartphone 10GB 3GHz"), and dots will be placed from this width, not from the last row("camera") as I need.

Comment: right... not so trivial... in my solutions the dots wouldn't start right after the 'camera' word, but at the right edge of TV no. 1. If it is not acceptable for you, you can use the onMeasure() methods of view, measure the width of text, TextView, and thw screen, and put as many dots that will fit the remaining space between name and the number (knowing also the width of one dot). This however may consume a lot of memory resources, since there may be a lot of computations required. Did you try that?

Answer (score 2):

I've changed Serg_'s CheckinfoTextView class so that it both works in the eclipse layout editor, but also adds spaces if possible, to put the page number as close to the right side as possible. I've also changed a bit how it is used.

To accomplish:

```
Milk...................23
Chocolate cookies......24
```

set the text to 'Milk 23' and 'Chocolate cookies 24' respectively

The number of spaces is rounded to nearest rather than rounded down, so it's better to put the number a little bit over to the right rather than too much to the left

```
public class DotAutofillTextView extends TextView {

private int availableWidthForDots;
private int widthOfSpace;
private int widthOfDotWithSpace;

public DotAutofillTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DotAutofillTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public DotAutofillTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    int width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int lastLineWidth = (int) getLayout().getLineWidth(getLineCount() - 1);
    availableWidthForDots = width - lastLineWidth;
    int widthOfOneDot = getWidthOfOneDot();
    int widthOfTwoDotsWithSpace = getWidthOfTwoDotsWithSpace();
    widthOfSpace = widthOfTwoDotsWithSpace - (widthOfOneDot * 2);
    widthOfDotWithSpace = widthOfSpace + widthOfOneDot;
    int requiredDots = getRequiredDotsNumber();
    if (requiredDots != 0) {
        int spaces = getRequiredSpacesNumber(requiredDots);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String text = getText().toString();
        result.append(text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(' ')));
        setText(result.toString());
        StringBuilder dots = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < requiredDots; ++i) {
            dots.append(" .");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; ++i) {
            dots.append(" ");
        }
        result.append(dots.toString());
        result.append(text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1));
        setText(result.toString());
    }
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}

private int getRequiredSpacesNumber(int requiredDots) {
    float remain = (1f * availableWidthForDots) % (1f * widthOfDotWithSpace);
    return (int) ((remain / widthOfSpace) + 0.5f);
}

private int getRequiredDotsNumber() {
    if (getLayout() == null) {
        return 1;
    }
    int numberOfDots = availableWidthForDots / widthOfDotWithSpace;
    return numberOfDots;
}

private int getWidthOfTwoDotsWithSpace() {
    return getStringWidth(". .");
}

private int getWidthOfOneDot() {
    return getStringWidth(".");
}

private int getStringWidth(String text) {
    Rect dotBounds = new Rect();
    getPaint().getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), dotBounds);
    return dotBounds.width();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If '.'(dots) is your basic requirement then you can try like this..

My suggestion, Use only I `TextView` to fit in Beer...10     (hitch)

try like this..

```
    int label_len = 10;//Edit as per your requirement
     String MoneyValue = "20";
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(your id);
    tv.setText("Beer");

    if(tv.getText().length() < label_len){
        for(int i = tv.getText().length(); i < label_len; i++){

           tv.setText(tv.getText()+".");
        }
    }
tv.setText(tv.getText() + MoneyValue);
```

This is a sample with hardcoded value, you can try to add dynamically...

Hope this helps...

Comment: How I can count label_len?

Comment: `label_len` is something which will keep your number of dots impact on your textview.. Suppose `label_len = 10`, and word is BEER then setText will be `BEER......` and if word is Cookies then `Cookies...`  So, you can increase label_len value to get more dots without hampering display..

Comment: I don't know exactly how many dots should I put. Suppose I have a RelativeLayout which has children: 2 TextViews (First - for text with dots, Second - for value), the second TextView is aligned to right, first TextView is aligned to the left of parent and to_left_of second TextView. I just need to fill empty space of first TextView with dots before the second TextView.

Comment: Haven't you read my answer properly, I said you can do with 1 textView, in you case RelaytiveLayout will now have only 1 child(textView)...

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can achieve this by using layout.xml only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:![enter image description here][2]layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:weightSum="1">    
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"          
          android:text="Milk.................................................................................................................................." />
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"             
            android:text="20" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This solution will work for all the device with different resolutions.

Comment: Yes, But text I need to put dynamically. And singleLine=true  is unsuitable for me - The text can be more then one line.

Comment: Edited the answer. You can add the text dynamically. The second textview will get adjusted to bottom. Just run it by adding text dynamically.

Comment: If set singleLine=true it works properly. But without enabled this param the text jumps to the next row, e.g.: Milk............................................................................................................................................................................20
But I need:
Milk................20

Comment: Thats what you wanted rite ?? if not then remove android:gravity="bottom" from the second textview

Comment: The removal of android:gravity="bottom" didn't help

Comment: Attached screenshot after removing android:gravity and android:layout_gravity

Comment: Yes, that's it. But what I need is to display it without the second row with dots.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32611/discussion-between-brijesh-thakur-and-user1731626)

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative layout:

```
TextView View TextView
```

The first set the width to wrap content, and below the text view of the previous row.
The second view, set to to right of first text view, and use a background drawable with dots that repeat horizontally. Set the width to match parent.
The last view, set to right of middle view and width to wrap content and aligned to right of parent.

Comment: This is similar as Jacek Milewski answer. My comment is below.

Comment: Yes indeed. But the dots as a background is more elegant than a lot of dots in a text view. Using a relative layout will make each row independent so it will work. Trust me.

Comment: Unsuitable for me, bcz the View (the second element) will be placed from width of whole TextView, but I need to place the dots from width of the last row of TextVeiw (e.g. Smartphone in the question).

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and found this solution using ConstraintLayout:

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Phone"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="...................................................................................................."
                android:maxLines="1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/item"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/price"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="100"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                />
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```